# bag of words in an online configuration, for classification / clustering

Tags: clustering, classification, text-mining, image-processing, sequential-analysis

I have a set of image documents. I extract text keywords from this images using OCR to represent each image as a bag of words (a vector where each value is the number of occurrence of a word in the document). Then I can apply a classification or clustering algorithm on the obtained dataset.

However, this vector representation as bag of words is possible only if I have the entire set of documents (to be able to have the entire vocabulary, i.e. all words). How can I do that (i.e. extract my bag of words) if I'm in an online configuration (using an online clustering) where the documents are available one by one (for a data stream) and each document should be processed as soon as it is available ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use sparse vector formats, it should not be a problem to add new dimensions later on. In sparse vectors, unset dimensions default to 0, usually. Since that is "word not present" it should be fine.

So, have you tried it? Where exactly does the problem arise?

Comment: Is there any other formats for bag of words than the "sparse vector formats" ? If I add a new dimension each time I find a new word, we will have an unbounded dimensionality. is it possible to dynamically keep only the significant words, as we go ?

Comment: Why do you need a finite dimension for a sparse vector format?

Comment: Because the classical distances become weakly discriminant when we have a highly multidimensional and sparse data

Comment: Pretending that you have fewer dimensions does not change this at all. It does not actually change the distance values if you leave away zeros! Plus, you *can* keep a global list of dimensions to skip, i.e. project your data to some subspace. This does not at all collide with sparse vectors.

Comment: Ok, then I'll use sparse vector format. Another question would be: is it more difficult (compared with low dimensional dense data) to learn a distance metric function (say a vector of weights for a weighted euclidean distance) using some labelled data, when the data-points are actually bag of words (multidimensional and sparse vectors) ?

Comment: I havn't tried that. Usually, one would use cosine distance instead of Euclidean as it behaves a bit more nicely in high dimensional data. I don't know if it supports weights.

Comment: Another problem is that we can have may words which are frequent but do not relate to the topic of the document such as "the", "of", "to" etc ... and I hopefully prefer the method to be independent from the language.

Comment: Google for "Stopwords". However, I read that depending on the method you do no longer need to remove them, they may automatically get a low weight if they are omnipresent. See http://xapian.org/docs/stemming.html
Anyway, just mark those dimensions for skipping during distance computation!